# R lowest non zero in multiple matrices

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a selection of n matrices, I'd like the lowest non zero number, otherwise return zero. I'd like to do this using a construct that can be applied to matrix objects rather than iterating across each element, due to the size of the matrices I'll be using. An Example....

```
> A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    0

> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    3    0

> C
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    0
```

I'd like it to return...

```
> FinalMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    0
```

If anyone has any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: Will your matrices contain any NA values?

Comment: No, they would all be integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
A <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0), 2, 2)
B <- matrix(c(2, 3, 2, 0), 2, 2)
C <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 0), 2, 2)
dat <- list(A, B, C)

out <- do.call(pmin, lapply(dat, function(x) ifelse(x == 0, Inf, x)))
out <- ifelse(is.infinite(out), 0, out)
```